# Table.SelectRows when one column concatenated and the other is split into rows

Tags: join, dax, relationship, powerquery, lookup

I want to create a custom column using Table.SelectRows (or any other expression) that does the following. In my Table1, I have a column called Cities that lists values separated by a comma:

| Country | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| France | Paris, Lyon, Marseille |
| Germany | Berlin, Munich, Dortmund |

In my Table2, I have a Sister_Cities column like this:

| City | Sister_Cities |
| --- | --- |
| Paris | Rome |
| Lyon | Birmingham |
| Lyon | Guangzhou |
| Lyon | Montreal |
| Lyon | Addis Ababa |
| Marseille | Genoa |
| Marseille | Glasgow |

I know the logical thing to do would be to split the first table into rows and then do a join based on the Cities and City columns, but I want to keep them concatenated so that I have a new column in Table1 that looks like this:

| Country | Cities | Custom.Sister_Cities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Paris, Lyon, Marseille | Rome, Birmingham, Guangzhou, Montreal, Addis Ababa, Genoa, Glasgow |

What's the best way to achieve this? Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Unrelated to your post, but keep in mind that their are many cities around the world that share names (e.g., Rome, Italy; Rome, GA (USA); Rome, IL (USA)...). Might be helpful to either have a primary key for each city name or at least a concatenated locale string (e.g., country > province > city) to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably still do it that way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Cities", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Cities"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Cities"}, Table2, {"City"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Sister_Cities"}, {"Sister_Cities"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table2", {"Country"}, {
    {"Cities", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Distinct([Cities]), Text.From), ", "), type text},
    {"Sister_Cities", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Sister_Cities], Text.From), ", "), type text}
    })      
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

alternate, probably slower

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Sisters= Table.Buffer(Table.Group(Table2, {"City"}, {{"Sister_Cities", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Sister_Cities], Text.From), ", "), type text} })),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Transform(Text.Split([Cities],", "), (x)=> try Table.SelectRows(Sisters, each [City] = x)[Sister_Cities]{0} otherwise null)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Sister_Cities", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls([Custom]), Text.From), ",")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```